# Vue change-component with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, methods

Dear Stackoverflow Community,

I am working on my first Vue-Project with TypeScript. Now I have a Two-Columns-Layout and I try to change only the left side component with one click on a button. But I receive an error code with my following method "changeComponent":

```
  methods: {
    changeComponent(payload) {
      this.componentName = payload.componentName;
    }
  }
```

Error: Parameter 'payload' implicitly has an 'any' type.

I am new with TypeScript and would be very grateful for all your inputs.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript doesn't know about the type of `payload` object. You have to define the types of your `Object` like this:

```
interface ObjectChange {
  componentName: string;
  //or
  componentName: number;
  ...
}

const Object = <objectChange[]>require('../data');
```

Hopefully this helps you out!

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer! I am working the first time with vue and have no knowledge of typescript or javascript. I chose now to change my project to a javascript project because there are more tutorials and answers on vue-projects with javascript! But thank you so much!